# MIP^*=RE and quantum computation

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, computability-theory, quantum-mechanics

I recently learned about the [MIP^*=RE result](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04383). I have to admit that I don't understand big parts of this paper and I am barely familiar with quantum physics. I hope my questions below make sense.

I copy the basic definitions:

IP= the class of languages with an randomized interactive proof system (that runs in polynomial time)

MIP= the class of languages with an multiprover interactive proof system

MIP^* = the class of languages with a classical polynomial-time verifier interacting with multiple quantum provers sharing entanglement.

R.E= the class of recursively enumerable languages

It was known previously that MIP=NEXP (non-deterministic exponential time) and that MIP$\subsetneq$ MIP$^*$, but it was expected that MIP$^*$ wouldn't be "very far" from MIP, definitely within the computable.

My questions:

1. Since the 1930's there have been some very clear bounds on what is computable (e.g. by a Turing machine) and what is not. Later developments, e.g. multi-tape Turing machines, non-deterministic Turing machines, Turing machines with randomization etc. can be seen as efforts to "speed-up the computations" but without changing what is computable. A function computable by a non-deterministic Turing machine is also computable by a deterministic Turing machine, although the former may run in polynomial time while the latter in exponential time. I always thought that quantum computations will bring in some sort of "exponential speed-up" but again without changing the underlying notion of computable, i.e. quantum computable = computable by a classical Turing machine.

> In view of this new result is there a reason to believe otherwise? In particular, is it possible that quantum computable languages = r.e. languages?

2. Although proof assistants are in infancy right now, it is expected that in the future will play a vital role in the development of Mathematics, much like the role computers play in chess today.

> Are there any consequences of the above result for the development of proof assistants?
> At least in theory, is there any hope that problems which are intractable by classical computers will be tractable by quantum computers?

This is more like a dream, but can quantum computations give proof assistants the boost they need to come into play in everyday Mathematics?

Comment: 1. No, "quantum computable = computable by a classical Turing machine" is an already known result. In classes like MIP* one assumes that provers have perfect knowledge, which is not simulateable with either classical or quantum computers. 2. I would expect there are some hopes like that, but I don't think any step from MIP* = RE result.

Comment: @Wojowu Do you have an reference for "quantum computable = computable by a classical Turing machine" ?  This answers (1).

Comment: @Wojowu Is the any result (or conjecture) that quantum machines can be (exponentially) faster than classical machines?

Comment: Q1: _"Do you have a reference for `quantum computable = computable by a classical Turing machine' ?_ A1: This follows immediately from the fact that any quantum computation can be simulated by a classical computer with exponential overhead. Q2: _Is there any result (or conjecture) that quantum machines can be (exponentially) faster than classical machines?_ A2: The conjecture is that the complexity class BQP is a strict superset of BPP.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you for the answers. I don't know the class BQP, but I can look it up. If the conjecture is true do we get a "speed-up" using quantum computers? If yes, what sort of speed up?

Comment: this would be a bit long for a comment, I have expanded in the answer box

Comment: The reasons that proof assistants have not yet come into play in everyday mathematics are almost entirely of a sociological and engineering nature (e.g., user-friendliness). In the vast majority of cases, computational complexity has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @TimothyChow I don't agree with this. If computers were to provide a faster way to do Mathematics, Mathematicians would learn how to "code" and use them. User-friendliness would follow. The use of computers in everyday Mathematics is limited not just for sociological reasons.

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos I think you're confusing "faster way to do mathematics" with "faster running times of proof assistants." Using proof assistants today is indeed *not* a "faster way to do mathematics" for most mathematicians, but the bottleneck is *not* the running time of proof assistants. If you're imagining that a proof assistant could help me prove a lemma that I can't see how to prove myself, well, in the vast majority of cases, this is currently a pipe dream. The state of artificial intelligence is nowhere near that, and I repeat, the bottleneck is *not* computational speed.

Comment: @TimothyChow So the problem is not sociological or user-friendliness, but the development of AI. In any case, this is an interesting discussion, but I don't think we can continue it here in the comments section.

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos I agree we should wrap up the conversation. But I will reiterate that the reasons that proof assistants have not yet come into play in everyday mathematics are almost entirely sociological/engineering-related. True, they're not as powerful as Data from Star Trek or HAL from 2001. But the software is already powerful enough to be potentially very useful to many mathematicians. I recommend that you take the time to investigate why mathematicians aren't using them before stating strong opinions about the reasons. I think you'll find that the answers are sociological.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q1:** *"Do you have a reference for `quantum computable = computable by a classical Turing machine' ?*
**A1:** This follows immediately from the fact that any quantum computation can be simulated by a classical computer with exponential overhead.

**Q2:** Is there any result (or conjecture) that quantum machines can be (exponentially) faster than classical machines?
**A2:** The conjecture is that the complexity class BQP is a strict superset of BPP.

BQP is the class of decision problems solvable by a quantum computer in polynomial time, while BPP is the class of decision problems solvable by a probabilistic Turing machine in polynomial time. Both BPP and BQP are defined in terms of randomized algorithms, which
are allowed to make random choices and need to reach the desired result with probability greater than 2/3.

If BQP is strictly larger than BPP, a quantum computer can provide an exponential speed-up (from non-polynomial to polynomial). This would imply that the "strong" (or "extended") Church-Turing thesis is false: a probabilistic Turing machine (which models BPP) cannot *efficiently* (= in polynomial time) simulate a quantum computer (which models BQP). The simulation is certainly possible if we allow for an exponentially long time, so the basic Church-Turing thesis still holds.

Comment: @CarloBeenakkker Thank you for the answer. As this is a follow-up to the answer provided by wojowu in the comments, I will wait to see if wojowu wants to post an answer too. If not, I will accept this, although it answers only the first of my original questions (and two of my additional questions in the comments).